# Putting dynamic objects in order

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have a code and is working perfectly! But the output order is wrong, I tried everything to put it in order but I failed. Can you help me?

```
...
var cdns_available = {};
$.ajax('https://cdn1.server.com/status.php').catch(function(e) { return done[1] = true; }).then(function(response) { cdns_available['cdn1'] = parseInt(response); done[1] = true;});
$.ajax('https://cdn2.server.com/status.php').catch(function(e) { return done[2] = true; }).then(function(response) { cdns_available['cdn2'] = parseInt(response); done[2] = true;});
$.ajax('https://cdn3.server.com/status.php').catch(function(e) { return done[3] = true; }).then(function(response) { cdns_available['cdn3'] = parseInt(response); done[3] = true;});
$.ajax('https://cdn4.server.com/status.php').catch(function(e) { return done[4] = true; }).then(function(response) { cdns_available['cdn4'] = parseInt(response); done[4] = true;});
$.ajax('https://cdn5.server.com/status.php').catch(function(e) { return done[5] = true; }).then(function(response) { cdns_available['cdn5'] = parseInt(response); done[5] = true;});

...

for (var key in cdns_available) {
    var value = cdns_available[key];
    $("#status_div").append(key + " server: " + value + "<br>");
}
```

And the output is something like this:

```
cdn1 server: 50
cdn4 server: 133
cdn3 server: 28
cdn2 server: 19
cdn5 server: 117
```

or sometimes:

```
cdn5 server: 177
cdn4 server: 112
cdn1 server: 18
cdn2 server: 97
cdn3 server: 49
```

How can I put "cdn{num}" in order? Like this:

```
cdn1 server: 45
cdn2 server: 17
cdn3 server: 48
cdn4 server: 110
cdn5 server: 38
```

I tried this:

```
Object.entries(cdns_available).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
//Error: Uncaught TypeError: a.localeCompare is not a function
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Hardcode the output with the specific order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.entries` returns an array of *arrays*. In order to use `localeCompare` on the *keys*, access the 0th item in each array, and compare:

```
Object.entries(cdns_available)
.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
})
.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  $("#status_div").append(key + " server: " + value + "<br>");
});
```

But it would be far more elegant to use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(
  [
    'cdn1',
    'cdn2',
    'cdn3'
    // ...
  ]
  .map(cdn => Promise.all([cdn, $.ajax(`https://${cdn}.server.com/status.php`)]))
)
  .then(responses => {
    responses.forEach(([cdn, response]) => {
      $("#status_div").append(cdn + " server: " + response + "<br>");
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is working now!! I'll mark this answer as correct in seven minutes

Comment: Hello, do you know how can I compatibilze this script to old versions of IE? I'm getting errors on arrows using IE

Comment: Best to always write in the latest and greatest version of the language, and then transpile down to ES5 for obsolete browsers - this makes the development code easy, concise, and readable, while allowing old browsers to understand it. Usually you can use Babel for this: https://babeljs.io To include new prototype functions and objects, use polyfills: https://www.polyfill.io/

Comment: Of course, you can also re-write the code manually, but that's tedious and not a good, maintainable solution IMO

Comment: @CertainPerformance what is the best site to learn about promises and its supported methods?

Comment: This looks like a good introduction: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises